# Tensorflow won't download on my Raspberry Pi 4 and keep getting the same error message

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to download TensorFlow on my raspberry pi 4 but I keep getting the error that it "could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow == 1.11.

I tried doing "sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev" but even still I get the same message and am completely lost now on what to do.

Please help. How can I successfully download TensorFlow on my Raspberry Pi 4 and fix the error?

Comment: Which build instructions/tutorial are you following?

Comment: I'm trying to do donkey car so I am using these instructions at https://github.com/autorope/donkey2 but cannot get past "pip install -r drive_requirements.txt". I got the error message as I stated in the question so I tried doing "sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev" and still same error message.

Comment: Looks like you aren't the first: https://github.com/autorope/donkey2/issues/4 but might want to look at: https://github.com/autorope/donkey2/issues/2